# Disabling networking stops emitting data from realm

Tags: android, retrofit, realm, rx-java, retrofit2

I am facing a problem with **Retrofit** and **Realm** with **RxJava**:
I have a realm observable using `Observable.just(realm.copyFromRealm(realm.where(FooBar.class).findAll()))` and an retrofit observable using `mFooBarService.getFooBars()`.
I want to combine those so that first the database (realm) and then the api (retrofit) emits the data. I do this by concating them: `Observable.concat(realmObservable, apiObservable)`

This works good. I can also stop my api server, everything is working fine because the database has the data. Now the problem: **if I turn off networking** on my mobile phone (wifi, mobile data) **no data is received** by the observer. I thought that the observer first receives the database data and then a timeout or connection error? Instead I only get an error.

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**
Ok, I try to clarify what I mean.
It looks like this if I have network connection but the server is down:
`realmObservable.concat(apiObservable)
-----A---B---C---D---|---ERROR-------->`

So I get the data and then an error
But when the server is down it looks like this above too but instead I only get an error and not the data first.
I hope you understand me now.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting onError call from Retrofit and not from Realm. Your design of concatenation of Realm + Retrofit seems fine, what you are missing here is error handling for Retrofit when there is no internet connection. You can verify this by commenting all Realm code, and still receiving Error.

There are 2 ways to fix this,

- Check for internet connection availability before making retrofit
  call
- Add custom error handling in retrofit

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that I get the error from retrofit, but before the error is catched I do not get data from realm.

Comment: Just to be clear, if you are using .first in your concat and none of your source(realm and retrofit) has any result for you, it will throw an error, and I guess as you mentioned, you are catching that error, AFAIK if Realm has data, regardless of internet connection it will return the same, can you share full code where this is happening for better clarity.

Comment: This is still not enough, share some solid information like, what exact error are you getting, how the code looks like.